# Get td hidden value by on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, hidden

How to get the td hidden value by the jQuery

I tried with below codings

```
$pre_schedules ="<tr id='trvalue'><td onclick='showData1()' type='hidden' id='datetime' name='datetime' value='".$full_date."' class='realday available'></td></tr>";

<script>

    function showData1 () {
        var id = jQuery(this).find('td:hidden').val();
        //alert(id);
    }

    $('tr#trvalue').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).find('td#datetime').val();
        alert(id);
    });

</script>
```

How to get fulldate hidden value

Comment: is there code missing here? has $pre_schedules already been injected into the dom? $('td#datetime').val() should be correct so Im guessing it might be how you are entering the $pre_schedules and possibiliy needing $('tr#trvalue').on('click', function rather then $('tr#trvalue').click(function

Comment: td type=hidden ?? Never saw that...

Comment: Try using proper HTML. `td` does not have a `type` or a `value` attribute. It is invalid and jQuery `.val()` will not work either.

Comment: if `td` is empty it's hidden, not html outlayed, so see my answer and test case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#datetime').live('click',function () {
 var id = $(this).attr('value');
 alert(id);
 });
```

This works for me

Comment: Not sure what jQuery version OP uses, but `.live` has been long deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

change:

`type='hidden'`

to:

`style='display:none'` or `style='visibility:hidden'`

Answer (score -1):

Based on your original code. This should work.

```
$pre_schedules ="<tr id='trvalue'><td onclick='showData1()' type='hidden' id='datetime' name='datetime' value='".$full_date."' class='realday available'></td></tr>";

    <script>

        function showData1 () {
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('value');
            alert(id);
        }

        $('tr#trvalue').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).find('td#datetime').val();
            alert(id);
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. even you don't write a proper selector.

Answer (score -1):

See [here](http://tarex.ru/testdir/test4.php) the test case, without jQuery.

```
$full_date=date('Y-m-d');
$pre_schedules ="<table border=1><tr id='trvalue' onclick='alert(this.cells[0].attributes.value.nodeValue);'><td type='hidden' id='datetime' name='datetime' value='".$full_date."' class='realday available'></td></tr></table>";
echo $pre_schedules;
?>
```